# How to skip libraries from scan with JarScanFilter in Tomcat 8.5?

Tags: java, tomcat

I migrated from Tomcat 8.0.x to Tomcat 8.5.28. Tomcats default `JarScanner` now tries to scan non-existing derbyLocale_*.jar files and runs into FileNotFoundExceptions. Apparently, some manifest files are scanned and they refer to those *.jar files.

There was and is no specific configuration for the JarScanner and the 8.0.x version did not show this behavior. I tried the following modification of my context.xml but it has no effect.

```
<Context>
  <JarScanner>
    <JarScanFilter 
      tldSkip="${tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip},derbyLocale_*.jar"/>
  </JarScanner>
</Context>
```

But adding the glob "derbyLocale_*.jar" to the property "tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip" in catalina.properties (and not modifying the context.xml) works just fine.

Comparing the JarScanner documentation between 8.0.x and 8.5.x versions shows no difference in default configuration and behavor. Yet, the default behavior is to scan manifest files and for JARs referenced in those manifests.

This leads to the assumption that

1. Tomcat 8.0.x fails to scan for those JARs
2. Tomcat 8.5.x fails to skip those JARs when told so via context.xml

My preferred way to skip those JARs is the context.xml. How can I achieve it?

**Edit:** full stack trace of the FileNotFoundException is below.

```
2018-03-13T17:59:45,974 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] StandardJarScanner: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MyCompany/MyProduct/tomcat/lib/derbyLocale_cs.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProduct\tomcat\lib\derbyLocale_cs.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:188) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374) ~[tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309) [tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:266) [tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229) [tomcat-util-scan.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1897) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1125) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839) [catalina.jar:8.5.28]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_162]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
```

Comment: What is the name of the actual file you are trying to skip? What is telling Tomcat that the `derby` libraries exist in the first place? Tomcat's standard `jarsToSkip` doesn't include anything about Derby.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz The project uses some JARs from Apache Derby. They are put in Tomcats `lib` directory (e.g. derbyclient.jar, derbynet.jar, derbytools.jar). Some refer to the derby locales which haven't been used before. The locales that are to be skipped are listed here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevin38113.html

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace of the `FiltNotFoundException` into your question?

Comment: Thanks for hint. Don't know why more people don't hit this. I'm using embedded tomcat under maven. I added `System.setProperty("tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip", "derbyLocale_*.jar");`